# Why won't my simple Angular.js app work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this will not be considered a good Stackoverflow question, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why this won't work (based on [Angular's own tutorials](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) I'm following) and I have nobody to ask.

I'm opening my html in a browser. The file looks exactly like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head ng-app="MyFirstApp">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var mod = angular.module("MyFirstApp", []);
        mod.controller('myController', function($scope){
            alert("Hi");
            $scope.a = 5;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
<h1> My Body </h1>
<div>
    <h1>{{a}}</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is loading well, and there are no errors in the console. I double and triple checked and all the variables are spelled correctly.

Can you tell me why it's not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

put

`ng-app="MyFirstApp"` in the html or body

like

```
<html ng-app="MyFirstApp">
```

OR

```
<body ng-app="MyFirstApp">
```

if ur define the ng-app like `<head ng-app="MyFirstApp">` this, it indicates the your app. scope is lays with in the `head` tags, so its not visible to the body but only with in `head`.

Comment: aw dammit. Right on. I'm so sorry I didn't catch that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hey you just overlooked the angular nesting. A controller is linked to the module and is accessible within module.
In your case you have defined the module **MyFirstApp** and added it to **head** tag. Therefore the linked controller is accessible within the decendent of head tag. But here you have added the controller  **myController** to the body tag which is outside the head tag.

Comment: A little hard to understand what you were saying at first, but I got it. Thanks